# Split the string from backward

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to split string into array with fix number of char but the counting should be from backwards. In the following example I want to split the string into array with set of 3 char:

```
InputString = '1234567'
```

Wanted:

```
OutputArray= [1,234,567]
```

Tried:

```
InputString.match(/.{1,3}/g)
OutputArray = [123,456,7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) regex.

```js
var InputString = '1234567';

console.log(
  InputString.match(/\d{1,3}(?=(\d{3})*$)/g)
)
```

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/tsCjLh/1)

---

With [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method with [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for asserting position to split.

```js
var InputString = '1234567';

console.log(
  InputString.split(/(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/)
)
```

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/6dr6TI/1)

Comment: @BhagwanThapa :  glad to help :)